# After GitLab upgrade the email address is missing from group member API calls

Tags: api, gitlab

We have recently upgraded to GitLab 7.10.4 and there appears to be a change in the API.  In the previous release it put the email address on the group members API call and now that appears to be removed.

If I call the API URL http://mygitlab.com/api/v3/groups/15/members?per_page=100&private_token=itsasecret

I get a list of the users but the email address is missing:

```
   {
     name: "Michael Ransley",
     username: "michael.ransley",
     id: 59,
     state: "active",
     avatar_url: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/88c8f05469e0ae00a904f21ccff6ed47?s=40&d=identicon",
     access_level: 50
   },
```

Any ideas on how I can get the email address back into this response?

Note: the user making the call is a gitlab admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into it, the code appears to be missing the email attribute.  I have added it and and created a pull request to ensure that it is added into future versions.

https://github.com/mransley/gitlabhq/commit/5de73237ae585ff70013c1ae38b4a88970133e26